# PropType not populating

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to create a container that loads the user details from a collection called `ProfileCandidate`. I'm using propTypes and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I believe it's a load order error because my propType loads an empty object. I know the container is running because it is subscribing to my `profileCandidate.private` request.

Path: `components/ContactDetails.js`

```
class ContactDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ProfileCandidate = this.props.profileCandidate;
    console.log("ProfileCandidate: ", this.props.profileCandidate);
    };
}

ContactDetails.propTypes = {
  profileCandidate: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate.private');
  var test = ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
  console.log("test: ", test);
  return {
    profileCandidate: ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}) || {},
  };
}, ContactDetails)
```

Comment: Have you tried to `render` the view? It is expected that the when the component is constructed it will get the empty object, as the publication did not have time to send data to the client. Don't expect the `props` in your constructor to include data that will be available to `render` only at a later time, after the container is re-run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createContainer` loads data asynchronously, so the initial state of profileCandidate will be `undefined`. You can see your data in the `createContainer` callback as you are in the execution context created by [`MeteorDataManager` in react-meteor-data line 107](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx) but before that the `ContactDetails` is rendered with empty props.

You should do logic based on `this.props.profileCandidate` only when it's loaded, so not in the `costructor` but in `render` or `componentDidUpdate` methods.

Please change the `propTypes` so the property is not required anymore as it will be loaded asynchronously. Please note that `React.PropTypes` is deprecated as of React v15.5. Please use the [`prop-types` library instead](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types).